# Make IFormFile function to work with model

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have a function in my controller that takes a file sent by an ajax call and saves it to a specified path. I was wondering how I could make this work with a model instead as I am hoping to send more data than just the image.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class PhotoViewModel
{
    // Other strings

    public IFormFile userimage { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:** Without model (working)

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile file)
{
    var filePath = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\me\documents\" + file.FileName);

    if (file.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

**Attempt at Version with Model:**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PhotoData(PhotoViewModel model)
{
    var filePath = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\me\documents\" + model.userimage.FileName);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.userimage.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await model.userimage.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

This attempt doesn't get me far. By setting a breakpoint I can see it fails at setting the filePath but I'm not sure how to work with the model. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message you are getting and what is the client side code you are using to send the API request?

You will have to use a FormData object and fill the FormData object with the required properties.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(add PhotoViewModel properties)
formData.append(userimage, <file>);
```